# Elasticsearch Angular app throwing Uncaught TypeError: _.extend is not a function

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch, requirejs

I am trying to build Elasticsearch Angular app. I am using require.js.

```
define([
'angular',
'elasticsearch'
],function(angular){
console.log("Entering es client app... ");
return angular.module('es',["elasticsearch"])                  
    .service('client', function (esFactory) {
        console.log("Register es client... ");
      return esFactory({
      host: 'http://localhost:9200',
      apiVersion: '1.4',
      log: 'trace'
    });
});
});
```

I have set paths

> paths : {
>       'angular' : '../bower_components/angular/angular',
>       'elasticsearch':'../bower_components/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.angular'
>       }

and added dependency

> 'elasticsearch':{
>      deps:[
>       'angular'
>       ],
>       exports:'elasticsearch'
>    }

But it is throwing the following errors. Anyone else faced this issue?

> Uncaught TypeError: _.extend is not a function40.__browserify_Buffer @ elasticsearch.angular.js:38901s @ elasticsearch.angular.js:4(anonymous function) @ elasticsearch.angular.js:424.../connection @ elasticsearch.angular.js:37262s @ elasticsearch.angular.js:4(anonymous function) @ elasticsearch.angular.js:415../lib/client @ elasticsearch.angular.js:18307s @ elasticsearch.angular.js:4e @ elasticsearch.angular.js:4(anonymous function) @ elasticsearch.angular.js:4
>
> require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function () {
>         return _;
>       }
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatchmakeError @ require.js:166intakeDefines @ require.js:1229localRequire @ require.js:1410context.configure @ require.js:1351requirejs @ require.js:1742req.config @ require.js:1753(anonymous function) @ main.js:4(anonymous function)

Comment: Looks like you uncorrectly define _(lodash?) object.

Comment: Sorry edited. Removed that and still find this error.

Comment: This issue was resolved. It was because of using bower install. Bower is not supported. I now used npm install. https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch. I am getting new errors. Continuing to troubleshoot in a new question.